# Prevent adding a record when there is a similar within a timeframe

Tags: mongodb

I would like to write a query that would not add the following to the document when there is already a record that matchs both `value1` and `value2` and when date is within 1 minute

Any tips?

```
const thing = {
  date: new Date(),
  value1: 'hello, world!',
  value2: 7,
}
db
    .collection('mycollection')
    .updateOne({myID: '123579'}, {$addToSet: {things: thing}})
```